# How to prevent audio to overlap itself when playing more than one tracks?

Tags: html, jquery, audio

I have 3 link blocks and I would like, if a user clicks on two of them, to mute one of the songs.

I am unfortunately a bit novice with jQuery/Javascript, but here is the code I have right, now, which doesn't work:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var isPlaying=false
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.play').click(function(){
        var audioID = "sound" + $(this).attr('id');
        var $this = $(this);
        var music = new Audio(audio);
        if (!isPlaying) {
            // Not playing, let's play
            isPlaying = true;
            music.play();
        } else {
            // Stop the music
            isPlaying = true;
            music.pause();
        };
    });
});
</script>
<audio loop id="sound1" src="3.mp3"> </audio>
<audio loop id="sound2" src="2.mp3"> </audio>
<audio loop id="sound3" src="3.mp3"> </audio>
```

I do have another code that plays the three songs assigned to its link blocks, but they overlap.

```
$('.play').click(function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    // starting audio
    var audioID = "sound" + $(this).attr('id');
    $this.toggleClass('active');
    if($this.hasClass('active')){  
        $("#" + audioID).trigger('play');
    } else {
        $("#" + audioID).trigger('pause');
    }
```

Any help, or pointers in the right direction, are more than appreciated!

Comment: I'm not sure how this is supposed to work? You have three audio elements somehow controlled from 1 button, yet that 1 button is supposed to start/stop the audio elements individually? Can you edit the question to please give a clearer description of your goal, and to also include all relevant HTML.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Yeah, I poorly worded the question :S Sorry!
A simple thing would be finding a way so that the audio does not overlap themselves if the user clicks a new Link Block to play new audio. SO, each link block plays audio but do not overlap themselves. Hopefully, that makes sense